# Общий метод для каста explicit и implicit operator

Tags: c#, .net, expressions

Есть 2 класса

```
class Class1
{
}

class Class2
{

    public static explicit operator Class2(Class1 value)
    {
        return new Class2();
    }

    public static implicit operator Class1(Class2 value)
    {
        return new Class1();
    }
}
```

У нас имеется объекты Type обоих классов.

Нужен общий метод умеющий кастовать в обе стороны (expression, emit...)

пример:

```
//метод конвертации. Возвращает object ибо у нас нет T
public object Convert(object source, Type targetType){
    //тут происходит преобразование source в Type 
    //source и type связаны expicit/implicit
}
var obj1=new Class1();
var obj2=Convert(obj1, typeof(Class2));

и наоборот

var obj1=new Class2();
var obj2=Convert(obj1, typeof(Class1));
```

explicit и implicit определены в одном классе, но каст с помощью них работает в обе стороны.

Что известно:

1. Convert.ChangeType требует реализации интерфейса IConvertible, что не подходит
2. C reflection можно, но он медленный.

Comment: что значит _метод умеющий кастовать в обе стороны_? попробуй добавить пример, как ты хочешь его использовать

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: а откуда предположение, что _Expression в других ответах внутри себя обращаются к Convert.ChangeType_? Вроде бы конверт напрямую вызывает операторы

Comment: @Grundy в других ответах на подобные вопросы в so, не внутри себя. Я из тех, что сначала гуглю и только потом пишу сюда. Есть еще Expression.Convert, но я не умею его готовить. Я вообще в Expression только на уровне чтения.

Comment: _Есть еще Expression.Convert_ - я про него и говорил

Comment: А что означает «expression, emit» в вопросе? И да, ваш метод должен работать _только_ для `Class1` и `Class2` или для _всех_ подобных комбинаций?

Comment: @VladD мне нужен результат., неважно expression или emit или любое другое средство (кроме рефлексии, которая медленная)

Comment: Ну, если «кроме рефлексии», то это значит, что другой, настолько же медленный способ не подойдёт тоже. В таком случае возникает вопрос, а почему вам это нужно? Возможно, у вас XY problem.

Comment: @VladD Сложно придумать "настолько же медленный" способ как рефлексия без использования рефлексии. Кодогенерация быстрее. Нет. Это не XY problem. Мне нужен конвертер, который пережует все. Очевидно, что кроме явного кодирования 100500 методов и рефлексии остается только кодогенерация. Я очень удивлюсь если вы найдете что-то другое, если даже generic тут не подходят (я четко обозначил, что у меня есть только Type).

Comment: И ещё непонятно, почему вы хотите передать reflection-информацию (а `Type` именно ей и является), но при этом отказываетесь от рефлексии. Почему сигнатура метода не `ConvertTo<T1>(T2 t2)`?

Comment: Возможно, тогда проблема в вашей архитектуре. Если в вашей модели (а больше нигде скорость не критична) нужно огромное количество конвертаций, что-то не так с иерархией классов.

Comment: Ну, а чем вам не нравится просто `if (source is Class1 c1) { return (Class2)c1; }` и т. д.?

Comment: @VladD мы не знаем конечный тип. Есть словать "тип->тип". Он и знает во что нужно сконвертить входящий объект. На выходе object что вполне устраивает. Рефлексию не хочется потому что "ну если есть более быстрые  методы, то разумно их использовать"

Comment: @vitidev: А есть словарь? Если есть словарь, то это меняет дело.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57574/discussion-between-vitidev-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача из разряда "а как это сделать". 
Нужно понимать, что результатом конвертации будет нужный тип, но приведенный к object. И что в другом месте потребуется явный каст.
Но перед нами стоит задача "cast" для implicit/explicit operator c Type.

У нас есть готовые типы и нет дженериков T.

```
Type srcType=typeof(TSource);
Type resultType=typeof(TResult);
```

Для решения проблемы берем generic-методы

```
//для сравнения
public static TResult GenericConvertObjParam<TResult>(object src)
{
      return (TResult)(dynamic)src;
}
public static TResult GenericConvertGenericParam<TSource, TResult>(TSource src)
{
     return (TResult)(dynamic)src;
}
```

Из которых с помощью рефлексии можно сделать методы с конкретными типами.

```
MethodInfo reflectionObjParam = typeof(...)
        .GetMethod("GenericConvertObjParam", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
         .MakeGenericMethod(resultType);

MethodInfo reflectionGenericParam = typeof(...)
         .GetMethod("GenericConvertGenericParam",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
         .MakeGenericMethod(srcType, resultType);
```

Далее можно вызывать Invoke и получить нужный результат

```
_reflectionObjParam .Invoke(null, new object[] {srcObj});
_reflectionGenericParam .Invoke(null, new object[] {srcObj});
```

Медленно, поэтому делаем кодогенерацию.

```
//Здесь Func<object, object>, ведь мы не можем написать сигнатуру Func<T,TResult>. 
//Также Delegate.DynamicInvoke ужасно медленный.

var func =
(Func<object, object>)_reflectionMethodInfoObjParam.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, object>));      
var result = func(srcObj);
```

С помщью Expressions.Convert задача не решается.

Замер времени для маленького тестового объекта .

```
прямой конверт (просто кодом): 7,7 ns
рефлексия (object параметр)  : 266,78 ns
рефлексия (generic параметр) : 227,30 ns     
delegate (object параметр)   : 39,52 ns
delegate (generic параметр)  : 40,21ns
```

ps: Если есть T, то  можно будет использовать Expressions.Convert, который на данном примере выдаст значение 16 ns.